# Dimension too large while plotting with pgfplots

Tags: errors, pgfplots, dimensions

I have the following pgfplots code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-8:2]
\foreach \i in {-10,-9.8,...,10} {\addplot+[smooth] {-x/\i+\i};}%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I need several line-plots in order for the parabolic pattern to emerge, hence the for loop with a 0.2 increment. Unfortunately, this gives me the `dimension too large` error. What can I do?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Besides the obvious 1/0 division, the question is not about math but about TeX, i.e. why pgfplots fails. pgfplots probably complains because whatever internal represenation of 1/0 is "too large" to be plotted. The solution is to use `restrict y to domain`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-8:2, restrict y to domain=-10:10]
\foreach \i in {-10,-9.8,...,10} {\addplot+[no markers, solid, smooth] {-x/\i+\i};}%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(Having said that, it is anyway dangerous to allow a division by zero in general.)

[image: emerging parabola]

Comment: Another day, another `pgfplots` option :)

Answer (score 5):

In the middle of the loop `\i`=0, so that there will be a division by zero. Mathematics generally does not like that (though interestingly the code compiles on my computer). So you have to split the loop into two loops, excluding zero:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-8:2]
    \foreach \i in {-10,-9.8,...,-0.2} {\addplot+[smooth] {-x/\i+\i};}%
    \foreach \i in {0.2,0.4,...,10} {\addplot+[smooth] {-x/\i+\i};}%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Once division by zero is allowed, 1 becomes zero, then all hell breaks loose. `:-)`

Comment: @Matthew: Now, what does that say about my computer?