# PGFPlots gnuplot contour ... dimension too large?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to make a contour plot with `pgfplots` and `gnuplot`, but I get the error "dimension too large". Why? That seems like a TeX error, I thought `gnuplot` was doing the calculations?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        view={0}{90},
        grid=major,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        xmin=-2,
        ymin=-2,
        xmax=+2,
        ymax=+2,
        unit vector ratio = 1,
        ]
    \addplot3[
        contour gnuplot={
            number=10,
            contour label style={
                nodes={text=black}
                }
            },
        contour/draw color={black},
        contour/label distance=1000pt,
        thick,
        samples=50]
        { 3*x^2 + 4*y^3 + 2*x^3 - 12*y };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I add `restrict z to domain=-20:30` (which should encompass all relevant output values of `f(x,y)=3*x^2 + 4*y^3 + 2*x^3 - 12*y` in the given domain), an output is produced but with only one contour (not `10` contours as desired).

I'm expecting something similar to:

[image]

Comment: Could you try to compile with the `lualatex` engine?

Comment: By the way, which command line do you use for the compilation?

Comment: @pluton I had compiled with `pdflatex -shell-escape` (my TextMate default).

Comment: gnuplot does the calculation, some point (hidden) in the output is still too large for tikz. use the keyword ` restrict y to domain' (look in the manual). http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13838/1871

Comment: @alfC See comment in question about `restrict z to domain=-20:30` (which I suspect is the relevant command in this case, since we're using `addplot3`. Do you know why restricting z domain might be limiting the number of contours?

Comment: Good question, one may think that even if this is the a sort of 3d plot, the direction z should be projected out. I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that even though I specified `xmin=-2`, `xmax=+2`, `ymin=-2`, `ymax=+2`,  `pgfplots` was still sampling outside this range. If I specify the domains explicitly using `domain=-2:2` and `y domain=-2:2`, compilation works.

Still, I really thought `gnuplot` was doing the calculation? So why was dimensions too large?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        view={0}{90},
        grid=major,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        xmin=-2,
        ymin=-2,
        xmax=+2,
        ymax=+2,
        unit vector ratio = 1,
        ]
    \addplot3[
        contour gnuplot={
            number=10,
            contour label style={
                nodes={text=black}
                }
            },
        contour/draw color={black},
        contour/label distance=1000pt,
        thick,
        domain = -2:2,
        y domain = -2:2,
        samples=50]
        { 3*x^2 + 4*y^3 + 2*x^3 - 12*y };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]